I ran into a problem trying to connect R studio with PostgreSQL
I wanted to connect my R studio with my PostgreSQL.
it gave me this error message:

Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) :    RPosgreSQL error:
could not connect postgres@localhost:5432 on dbname "postgres": SCRAM
authentication requires libpq version 10 or above

I tried running the following on R script but I got the error:
install.packages("RPostgreSQL")
require("RPostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
                 dbname = "postgres",
                 host = "localhost",
                 port = 5432,
                 user = "db_user",
                 password = "db_password")

I also have a question on where do you find the "db_user" and "db_password". I tried connecting my R with PostgreSQL by following tutorial online but most of them have to set up control panel (windows). im using M1 chip macOS, hence I'm not sure where to check for the user and the password.
I have also tried searching for similar questions here, but I haven't found one that asks about how to fix this error for the R language. (most of them are for python, and other languages)

The error you are getting indicates that you do not have the current version of the libpq library installed on your machine, which is the PostgreSQL C library used by the package for database connections.
A solution would be to update the library on your machine. Since you are using a Mac OS, you can run:
brew install postgresql

After that, reinstall the RPostgreSQL library and try to connect again to your database. Hopefully, it should work.
Another option will be to run your application in a docker container, if you do not succeed in updating the version of libpq on your computer due to any compatibility issue.

Hi I have tried updating the libpq (my libppq is version 16.3), and install the postgresql using brew but i still encountered the same error.

Are you still getting the exact same error as above?

yes, the exact same error

Maybe you can try using the other R PostgreSQL library RPostgres instead of RPostgreSQL and see if you do not encounter any errors connecting to your database.

I tried the RPostgres and it's working for me. my database are finally connected now. Thank you very much for the help.

My pleasure, Jordan.
